# facebook api query string issue

Tags: api, facebook, query-string

I develop a facebook api with asp.net , I have to send query string but this querystring may include special characters like ( ı, ç ö, ş, ğ ). When I send query string with special characters, facebook returns me an error-

> The URL http://apps.facebook.com/sportsfanarena/Results.aspx?s=13&co=3&ci=Bal%c4%b1kesir&g=0 is not valid.

The "ci" variable's value is "Balıkesir".

Is there any solution to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use URL encoding to send characters like that, though I may be mistaken.

[**Here is an online utility**](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) which will take text and encode/decode it in URL encoding.

Try encoding the word you are wanting to send using this utility, and then try your API request with the encoded text.

Comment: And, funnily enough, it encodes to exactly what's in the question (the 'ı' is 2 bytes of UTF-8).